# Can't find a calendar as Admin

Tags: google-workspace, google-calendar

An employee created a Google Calendar (Google Apps Premier edition) and has now left.

I, as admin, now want to get control over that calendar, but I can't even locate that calendar on my dashboard.

If I go to another employee/user who was initially shared/invited to that calendar, they see it. However, none actually have admin/manage on that calendar.

- How do I gain control over that calendar?
- How can I control *all* calendars on my domain?

Answer (score 1):

As a Super Admin, you have full permission (view/edit) to each calendar in the domain. Therefore, to get access to the user's primary calendar, just enter the user's email address in the "Add a coworker's calendar" box (underneath "Other Calendars").

[image: sneaky little box]

Note that this trick will only work for a user's primary calendar. If a user has created an additional calendar, you'll have to find that calendar (I suggest using the [GAM (free third-party tool)](https://github.com/jay0lee/GAM/wiki) command `gam user bob@acme.com show calendars` - the ID value can be pasted into the "Add a coworker's calendar" box so you can view it or added to your account with the command `gam calendar <calendar ID> add editor <your email>`.

Answer (score 1):

This is very similar to Jordan's answer, in that it involves GAM. With Windows Powershell I have used this very quick script in the past to enumerate **all** calendars in the domain. Feel free to adapt and improve. Easily ported to other scripting languages.

```
# For each Google Apps user list all of the calendars they're 
# subscribed to... by Charles Kelley Stevenson
#
# Replace P:\... with the path to your GAM executable or delete block
# entirely if on another OS

if (!($env:Path -like '*Google Apps Manager*'))
{
    $env:Path += ";P:\Programs\Google\Google Apps Manager\gam-3.06-windows-x64\gam-64"
    Write-Host -ForegroundColor Cyan "Adding Google Apps Manager to Path environment variable"
}

Write-Host -ForegroundColor Cyan "Checking to see if we're connected"
gam info domain

$list = gam print users

foreach ($entry in $list)
{
    if ($entry -eq "Email")
    {
        continue
    }

    Write-Host -ForegroundColor Cyan $entry

    gam user $entry show calendars
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to @Charlie Stevensons answer, the errors can be suppressed and only output the name of the calendar for those who actually have calendars.

```
$list = gam.exe print users

foreach ($entry in $list)
{
      if ($entry -eq "Email")
      {
          continue
      }

      $summary = gam.exe user $entry show calendars 2>&1 | Select-String -Pattern "Summary:"
      if ($summary)
      {
           Write-Host -ForegroundColor Cyan $entry
           $summary
      }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

User the account that still has access to the calendar. 
Go to Calendar settings and click "HTML" to get the URL of the calendar.
Copy that URL
Sign into your admin account
Paste and go to the calendar URL
click "+ Google Calendar" button in bottom right of the calendar.

I really wish Google would give you a way to see all active calendars within a domain. Maybe one day....

Hope this helps!

Trey